# Batch File to get most recent file where filename contains a substring

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to write a batch file to open the most recent Session Log from a logs file.

I have a bash script which will do exactly as I want on linux, by listing the contents of my logs folder in time order, grep for lines starting with Session and taking the most recent one. After that it will append that onto the file path and open it. The code for the bash script is as follows:

```
mostRecentLogFile=~/my/logs/folder/$(ls -t ~/my/logs/folder | grep ^Session | head -1)
displayFunction="gedit"
echo "Opening $mostRecentLogFile ..."
$displayFunction $mostRecentLogFile
```

However I essentially need to convert this script to a batch file to do the same thing on Windows.

I can go as far as opening the most recent file in the logs folder, but there are other types of log files and I need to get the most recent one that begins with the string "Session" so this code doesn't always open the correct file:

```
cd my\logs\folder
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR *.* /B /O:-D') DO notepad.exe %%I
```

Any suggestions on how to edit this code to filter the filenames for ones containing a substring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR *.* /B /O:-D \| findstr Session') DO notepad.exe %%I` ?

Comment: `DIR SESSION* /B /O:-D /A:-D /T:W` set this in FOR /F definition.

Comment: It seems that both of these comments would open multiple notepad instances, since multiple results could match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't the best approach, but seems to work

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR *.* /B /O:D') DO echo %%I |>nul findstr /B "Session" && set logfile=%%I
notepad.exe %logfile%
```

Instead of sorting in reverse order (newest first), it is sorted in the standard order (oldest first), so that the final assignment of `%logfile%` is the newest filename that starts with "Session".  After the first line `%logfile%` contains the filename of your logfile, the second line just opens it.

**Edit**:

Depending on your exact use case, it seems like this could be shortened something like

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR Session* /B /O:D /A:-D') DO set "logfile=%%I"
notepad "%logfile%"
```

Comment: That's great, thank you very much!

Just for interest, what exactly is being done differently between the first and second solutions, as the second one seems to work much more quickly?

Comment: The first is collecting all of the filenames in your directory, sorting them, and sending each one to the `findstr` built-in, then only setting the `logfile` variable when `findstr` agrees that the filename starts with "Session".  The second one only collects the filenames that match the pattern `Session*`, sorts this smaller set, and sets the `logfile` variable unconditionally.  The second method skips the need for the separate `findstr` tests altogether.